# Dekko Email Client - IMAP - How to set up outgoing (SMTP) mail settings

Tags: email

I have successfully configured an IMAP inbox account on Dekko on the Ubuntu Phone but can't find any button to allow me to configure the (outgoing) SMTP settings.

I'd be really grateful if anyone can cast some light on this?

(Of interest, there are no tags in the popular list that deal specifically with this and the restriction that one cannot add a tag without a certain points score is such that it is not really possible to properly tag this question.  It may be that it does exist somewhere but there are around 10+ pages of possible tags and no effective method of searching on them. I think this limitation should be addressed or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same as you did. Unfortunately you need to add a further SMTP account to your already existing IMAP account. Check out your e-mail server's settings for further details like port number and server name.

Now, I'm able to receive and send e-mails on my ubuntu phone ...

:)

Comment: Thank you very much for going to the trouble of providing me with that answer.  I will consult with my colleagues and see what we come up with.  If I find out more or an easier way of doing things or if there is something we can contribute to making this easier, I will let everyone know.

Comment: I am having this issue too with my works Office 360 email. I have set it up so I get the emails come in fine, but I am not able to send outgoing emails. I will check and add a new SMTP account tonight and post how I get on. Adding a new account for the SMTP settings should not be too much of an issue, but adding my work Office 360 account details to the IMAP was all I could do. Should these not work together and remove the need to add a separate SMTP account? Has anyone raised this in Launchpad?

Answer (score 0):

remember: Dekko it is now version 0.6.
It is true that you need to add a smtp-Server
And in this smtp is a fault. You can not copy your send e-mails into the sent-folder.
It not works. So you must send to yourself a blind-copy.
Christian from Munich